# Can i make another layer on a imageview for drwing

Tags: iphone, ios

> I want to make drawing on a background image and when i will erase that drawing then erase only drawing not background image?how can i achieve that task.by this code my background image is also erased.

```
   ` UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    previousPoint2 = previousPoint1;
    previousPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint mid1 = midPoint(previousPoint1, previousPoint2);
    CGPoint mid2 = midPoint(currentPoint, previousPoint1);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageDoodle.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    [imageDoodle.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageDoodle.frame.size.width, imageDoodle.frame.size.height)];


    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);


    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);

    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

     if(IsErase)
    {
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context,kCGBlendModeClear);
    }

    else
    {
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), redvalue, greenvalue, bluevalue, 1.0);
    }

    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 8.0);


    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

     imageDoodle.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `another` `UIImageView` to your  `imageDoodle`:

```
//Add outer ImgView for Drawing purpose
imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,imageDoodle.frame.size.width, imageDoodle.frame.size.height)];
imgView.userInteractionEnabled  = YES;
imgView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
[imageDoodle addSubview:imgView];
```

**EDIT** : Now use same code but use `imgView` for `drawing purpose`:

```
[imgView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageDoodle.frame.size.width, imageDoodle.frame.size.height)];
```

Set current image in `imgView`

```
imgView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Now set your `original image` with main `ImageView`.

Now `render` main `ImageView` to get `backgroundimage+drawing`

Comment: have u set current image in imgView like imgView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

Comment: yes.and i want to show final image =backgroundimage+drawing

Answer (score 0):

Add Transparent UIView to your ImageView And give its height and width proportionally to imageView or imagesize. And whatever you want to draw, draw in uiview and erase it .

Comment: give me example for that..